# What is the difference between the usage of %i, %d,%f in ROS_INFO("")?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ros-info

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see a lot of usage of like

ROS_INFO("%d")

ROS_INFO("%i")

ROS_INFO("%f")

used, is there a difference in the usage of them? If so, what are the differences. Is there like a webpage where this has been explained?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327729/what-is-the-difference-between-the-usage-of-%i,-%d,%f-in-ros_info(%22%22)?/) by [Dickson](https://answers.ros.org/users/43223/dickson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS_INFO and other ROS log functions follow the same format as the standard C printf function. You can find more information here http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

The ones you mention:

```
int decimal_integer_value = 5;
float float_pont_value = 10.0f;
ROS_INFO("%d", decimal_integer_value);
ROS_INFO("%i", decimal_integer_value);
ROS_INFO("%f", float_point_value);
```

Would output:

```
 5
 5
 10.0
```

%d and %i are equivalent and use to print decimal integer values, %f is used to print floating point numbers"

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2019-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dickson](https://answers.ros.org/users/43223/dickson/) on 2019-07-08**:
Thank you very much (: